# Is there any mention about Nala in Vedas?

Tags: vedas, nala

In Mahabharata and some puranas, we can find about Nala.

Is there any mention in vedas regarding Nala?

Comment: Please give a reason for down-voting.

Comment: What/who is Nala?

Comment: He is king of Nishadas. @Krishna Shweta

Comment: What makes you think Vedas should mention Nala?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I heard in a preaching that there are many Vedic secrets in Nala story, so I thought.

Comment: Vedic secrets and mentioned in the Vedas are not the same. Having Vedic secrets means story teaches similar to the teachings in the Vedas. There are many works and scriptures which teach teachings of Vedas but the characters in it do not find mention in the Vedas.

Comment: I think Nala and Damayanti were mentioned in Ramayana but not veda @hanugm